# Query MySql database with md5 passwords

Tags: php, mysql, connection

So I have in the database mysql.user the users stored with password encryption method(it is by default from what I know) and my database.users which have the login credentials user and password(password is encrypted with md5).
The problem is that I want to encrypt the inserted passwords(from form) using md5 with the user being able to query the database.

These are the login credentials as extracted from $_POST method of the form and
made them as session for easy use on connection:

```
$_SESSION['utilizator']=$utilizator; //user
$_SESSION['parola']=md5($parola); //password
```

And this is the DB connection included in every file where I need to query the database:

```
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', $_SESSION['utilizator'], $_SESSION['parola']);
if(!$link){
    die('Unable to connect to the database: ' . mysqli_error($link));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try not to use md5 cause it is not safe anymore.
Why are you connecting to the database with user credentials? You should have a password and user, specific for that and use it everywhere you need a DB connection and allow a user to alter the DB only if he passes your login (what you are doing is not safe), in other words those user credentials are for the DB and DB only, and only known by you.
After doing this you can save in a table user related stuff: pass and username encrypted how you want them, make a login that checks the encrypted pass and the DB pass if that is ok then make the queries.

EDIT:

Since you wnat to store the pass in a cookie or session this method will help since you can simply store the encrypted password and check if it is the same as the one in your DB.

Comment: Thank you,didn't knew that is better to use a specific user for mysql connection. In my mind I thought that it was better to get the user credentials for accesing the DB instead of putting the mysql connection in plain text in my db connection php file.

Comment: PHP is only seen by the server and the one that is writing the code :D and in the worst case scenario by someone that hacked in your server in which case the DB is already most likely compromised.

Answer (score 2):

i would advise you to trim ans sanitize the username and password before storing them in the session. As for the [mysqli_connect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php)
it takes 4 arguments

```
<?php $link = mysqli_connect("myhost","myuser","mypassword","mydatabase") or die("Error " .     mysqli_error($link));?>
```

Look at the examples on the php page for [mysql-_connect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php). Another thing that i have noticed with your code, why does the user have to login into the database? The database user and the app user have to be different for security reasons.

Comment: Thank you for your advice but I will select Krotz's answer as the best for me(tough your answer is proper also).Also I am using mysqli_connect without the database paramater and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL does not use md5 to store user passwords (at least by default). It uses the MySQL `PASSWORD()` function. If you use the password without running it through `md5()` it should work.

```
$_SESSION['parola']=$parola; //password
```

Comment: It works since I used it without md5, but the problem is that I want to store cookies for user login and I am not confortable with storing it as plain text in the cookie.